# Mini Games suited for workshops/class

Tags: flash

I'm going to give a course in flash game programming.
The course will consist of 4 x 2.5 hour units.
The participants have basic knowledge in AS3 but are lacking motivation..
What kind of mini games do you think are suited to learn the "art of casual game programming" without overcharging the participants.

Thanks,
Karl

Answer (score 1):

a space invader clone is good. It was also the first game I ever made

Answer (score 1):

Asteroids is good, with wrapping screen, a la [CronusX](http://www.candystand.com/play/cronusx).

And of course there's always tic-tac-toe for the *very* first lesson.

Comment: I'd second this, I learnt a lot in as3 by building an asteroids game.

Answer (score 0):

How about [bricks](http://www.kongregate.com/games/Stataen/simple-brick-game)?

This was the first game I made when I learnt how to code.

Answer (score 0):

Ive always enjoyed programming the classic game 'pong' when learning a new language, it teaches some important skills like collision detection and some very basic AI programming.

Answer (score 0):

Thank's for the answers so far. Breakout and Pong are nice games to start but the collision detection/reaction can pretty quick become kind of hard..

There's a chain reaction game called BoomShine that I think is pretty good for a first mini game: http://www.k2xl.com/games/boomshine/